# Template print function C++

Tags: c++, templates, printing

so far I wrote this:

```
template <typename TType>
void print_vector(const std::vector<TType>& vec)
{
    typename  std::vector<TType>::const_iterator it;
    std::cout << "(";
    for(it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++)
    {
        if(it!= vec.begin()) std::cout << ",";
        std::cout << (*it);
    }
    std::cout << ")";
}

template<>
template <typename T2>
void print_vector(const std::vector< std::vector<T2> >& vec)
{
    for( auto it= vec.begin(); it!= vec.end(); it++)
    {
        print_vector(*it);
    }
}
```

The first function works fine for things like `std::vector< double>` and so on. Now I want to be able to print `std::vector< std::vector< TType>>` things as well. The second part doesn't compile, but that's the "idea" I have of solving my task. Any suggestions on how to achieve that kind of behavior?

`Compilation Error: too many template-parameter-lists`

Comment: You cannot partially specialize a function, you need to create a new overload

Comment: Notice that your second `print` doesn't output extra `(, )` around inner vectors.

Answer (score 8):

Remove the `template<>` part, function template overloading would work fine.

```
template <typename TType>
void print_vector(const std::vector<TType>& vec)
{
    typename  std::vector<TType>::const_iterator it;
    std::cout << "(";
    for(it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++)
    {
        if(it!= vec.begin()) std::cout << ",";
        std::cout << (*it);
    }
    std::cout << ")";
}

template <typename T2>
void print_vector(const std::vector< std::vector<T2> >& vec)
{
    for( auto it= vec.begin(); it!= vec.end(); it++)
    {
        print_vector(*it);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may actually want to go for a more generic solution to the problem, allowing to print pretty much any iterable type:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Iterable>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Iterable& vals)
{
    for (const auto& val : vals)
        os << val << std::endl;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    auto simple_vec = std::vector<int>{3, 5 , 7};
    std::cout << simple_vec;
    auto nested_vec = std::vector<std::vector<int>>{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    std::cout << nested_vec;
}
```

For further improvements on this solution, you could try using SFINAE, to make sure the templated `<<` is only available for iterable types.

Comment: Your method catch **all**. I discourage that without SFINAE. I prefer OP's version actually.

Comment: and you forget to output `(, )`.

Comment: That's exactly why I added the part about SFINAE in the end, as it is way to aggresive by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your function to print base types and override for vector using itself recursively:

```
template<typename T>
void print( const T &t ) 
{ 
    std::cout << t; 
}

template<typename T>
void print( const std::vector<T> &v ) 
{ 
    std::cout << '[';
    for( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it ) {
         if( it != v.begin() ) std::cout << ',';
         print( *it );
    }
    std::cout << ']';
}
```

then you do not need to write special one for vector of vectors or vector of vectors of vectors and so on.

[live example](https://ideone.com/5rqG4X)

Comment: OP's version should already handle vector of vector of vector... but your version would allow vector of list of vector ... :-)